# Fill a Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have something like this hard-coded:

```
private string[,] m_RolesForUser = new string[,] {
    {"John","President,Chair"},
    {"Lisa","Chair"},    
    {"Mike","Executive,President,Chair"},
};
```

How would I fill this array if the datasource was made up of a table of roles and a table of users.  A user could have multiple roles.  Not sure what the syntax is to construct the code to support something like this.

Comment: As a general rule, if your language is C#, multi-dimensional array are more often part of the problem than part of the solution. Sadly their support is quite lacking.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I would recommend using some homebrewed structure or some other complex data structure such as a dictionnary of lists or arrays. I prefer having a full OO view, but then thats just my opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a `Dictionary` of a list of objects here? C# is an OO language, so using objects is much more preferred. The example below is using strings to fit your example, but you could even create a `Person` class and a `Role` class and have a `Person` tied to a list of `Role`s

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> roles = new Dictionary
    {
        {"John", new List{"President","Chair"}},
        {"Lisa", new List{"Chair"}},    
        {"Mike", new List{"Executive","President","Chair"}}
    }
```

To look for Lisa's roles:

```
//Just verifying that Lisa exists.
//If you try to access a non-existent key you will get an exception
var roleLookingFor = "Lisa";
if(roles.Contains(roleLookingFor))
{
    foreach(var role in roles[roleLookingFor])
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is in role '{1}'.", 
                                               roleLookingFor, role));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Can you tell me how I would read or iterate through the Dictionary looking for the roles "Lisa" has?

Comment: I just created a sample snippet of how you might find roles.

Answer (score 1):

You have different options for data structures. One Idea would be to have a class for the users and to store the roles as a list for each user

```
public class User
{
    public User ()
    {
        Roles = new List<string>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Roles { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can have a list of users

```
List<User> _users = new List<User>();
```

If you want to store more information for each role, you could have a Role class as well having a user list for each role.

The advantage of `List<T>` versus arrays is that lists grow dynamically.

Fill this structure like this

```
using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    string query = "SELECT ... FROM users LEFT JOIN user_roles ON ... ORDER BY UserID";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cnn)) {
        cnn.Open();
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            int userIdOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("UserID");
            int userNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("UserName");
            int roleIdOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("RoleID");
            int roleNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("RoleName");
            User user = null;
            while (reader.Read()) {
                int userID = reader.GetInt32(userIdOrdinal);
                if (user == null || user.ID != userID) {
                    user = new User { ID = userID };
                    user.Name =  reader.GetString(userNameOrdinal);
                    _users.Add(user);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(roleIdOrdinal)) {
                    user.Roles.Add(reader.GetString(roleNameOrdinal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Of cause you would use an approriate connection type, reader type, etc.)